# Why should constexpr functions contain exactly one return statement?

Tags: c++, constexpr, constexpr-function

Reading through [the `constexpr` specifier documentation on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), I've noticed that the standard says the following:

> [...] the function body [of `constexpr` function] must be either deleted or defaulted or contain only the following: [...] if the function is not a constructor, exactly one return statement.

What is the motivation behind imposing such a requirement? Although I can understand that this could potentially lead to a simpler implementation of the constexpr interpreter, I do not see the reason why this limitation had to be imposed.

Both clang 15.0.0 and gcc 12.2 compile `constexpr` functions with multiple return statements with [no problem](https://godbolt.org/z/h9dGzdPs6). Am I reading the standard wrong or was this just some "obsolete" decision that is no longer being followed?

Comment: cppreference isn't the standard?

Comment: That part has a note saying _(until C++14)_, so in newer standards this limitation doesn't exist.

Comment: @IlCapitano is correct, the note "until c++14" is bound to the whole list of bullet points, not only to the one bullet point you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It used to be a restriction when `constexpr` was introduced to the language in C++11. Basically, back then, constexpr functions could only consist of a single return statement (like a simple getter function). The scope of `constexpr` has been extended since then and it's now much more capable than before. I guess the restrictions were due to

1. it was a new feature back then, so the committee was conservative in its scope, and
2. <s>in a `constexpr` context, UB is not allowed, which means the compiler has to prove that you're not invoking UB. I assume this was easier to implement from a compiler vendor perspective.</s>

Comment: I do not think that the second point matters. Even with just one return statement C++11 `constexpr` functions are already Turing-complete and can evaluate basically arbitrary complex expressions. The really tricky UB cases (e.g. the ones related to indeterminate/unspecified order of evaluation) are still open issues and would have been there with a single return statement as well.